# Large file uploads with FastCGI and Lighttpd

Tags: c, fastcgi, lighttpd

I am trying to upload files using the fastcgi library (http://www.fastcgi.com/) with my compiled fcgi application.

When I upload a small file (<500KB) the upload succeeds. However when I upload files larger than 500KB, I get the 503 Error (Service Not Available). I can confirm that the entire file had been uploaded to lighttpd's temp directory in 1MB chunks.

For my testing, the max-request-size was set to 30MB, and my test file was 14MB in size.

Immediately after the file chunks had been uploaded, the log showed the following:

```
(mod_fastcgi.c.3058) got proc: pid: 2171 socket: unix:/tmp/fcgi.sock-0 load: 1
(network_writev.c.303) write failed: Bad address 7
(mod_fastcgi.c.3098) write failed: Bad address 14
(mod_fastcgi.c.1490) released proc: pid: 2171 socket: unix:/tmp/fcgi.sock-0 load: 0
```

And the assembled upload file was ~500KB.

Could any one please shed some light on this for me?

My fcgi application is listed below:

```
#include "fcgi_stdio.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>


void main(void)
{

    int count = 0;
    while(FCGI_Accept() >= 0) {
        char *contentLength = getenv("CONTENT_LENGTH");
        int len;

        if (contentLength != NULL) {
            len = strtol(contentLength, NULL, 10);
        }
        else {
            len = 0;
        }
        printf("Content-type: text/html\r\n"
               "\r\n"
               "<title>FastCGI Hello!</title>"
               "<h1>FastCGI Hello!</h1>"
               "Request number %d running on host <i>%s</i>\n",
                ++count, getenv("SERVER_NAME"));

        printf("<br />CONTENT_LENGTH = %d <br />\r\n", len);
        printf("<form enctype='multipart/form-data' method='post' action='?'><input type='text' name='text1' /><input type='file' name='file1'/><input type='submit' /></form>");
        printf("<hr />");

        fflush(stdout);

        FCGI_FILE * fileOut = FCGI_fopen("/tmp/fcgi.out", "w");
        if (fileOut) {
            int done = 0;
            while(done < len) {
                char buffer[1024];
                int i;
                int packetRead;

                packetRead = FCGI_fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
                if (packetRead < 0) {
                    break;
                }
                if (packetRead > 0) {
                    FCGI_fwrite(buffer, 1, packetRead, fileOut);
                    done += packetRead;
                }


            }
            FCGI_fclose(fileOut);
        }

        FCGI_Finish();
    }    
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Write error bad address is risen when the address location that you have given is invalid.

I don't know about FCGI_fread and FCGI_fwrite, but for their POSIX equivalents

```
FCGI_fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
FCGI_fwrite(buffer, 1, packetRead, fileOut);
```

Should be

```
FCGI_fread(&buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
FCGI_fwrite(&buffer, 1, packetRead, fileOut);
```

May be that helps.

And second:

```
size_t     FCGI_fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FCGI_FILE *fp);
size_t     FCGI_fwrite(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FCGI_FILE *fp);
```

May be better ?:

```
FCGI_fread(&buffer, sizeof(char), sizeof(buffer), stdin);
FCGI_fwrite(&buffer, sizeof(char), packetRead, fileOut);
```

Comment: Since buffer is typed as an array (of chars), I believe that passing without the ampersand is correct. The strange thing is, writing does occur to the specified output file, but only for the first ~500KB before the write error is thrown.

Comment: This answer is wrong. I agree with the comment above.

Comment: @wei, could you tell us, how did you solve this?